# [D cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, arraylist, classcastexception

I wrote below code. It get this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

```
double[] xyz = {1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222};
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

array.add(xyz);

double[] vals = new double[array.size()];

vals[0] = (double) array.get(0);
vals[1] = (double) array.get(1);
vals[2] = (double) array.get(2);
```

I have also search and see some post on Stack Overflow, but they do not make much me sense. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: This makes no sense, `array.add(xyz);`. It is of key importance to show us ***exactly*** what you're adding to that ArrayList. You should be using an `ArrayList<Double>` regardless.

Comment: It's not `D` but `[D`, ie an array of `double`s.

Comment: @MintyFresh That is not a duplicate, because the questions are not the same. But it is a related question that the OP should read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add an array of `double` values to an ArrayList, do this:

```
Double[] xyz = {...};
ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<>(); // note, use a generic list
array.addAll(Arrays.asList(xyz));
```

A `List` cannot store primitives, so you must store `Double` values not `double`. If you have an existing `double[]` variable, you can use [`ArrayUtils.toObject()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(double[])) to convert it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your problem is that you are trying to cast the type of 'xyz', which does not seems to be a double or the [Wrapper](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/java-wrapper-classes.php) associed (Double), into a double.

Since java can't transform the type of 'xyz' into a double a [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) is throw. You should try to add n double to your array like that (or even in a loop) :

```
ArrayList<Double> myListOfDouble = new ArrayList();
myListOfDouble.add(1.0);
```

And then using a for loop to populate your double[] vals like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < myListOfDouble.size(); i++)
    vals[i] = myListOfDouble.get(i);
```